# Jenkins and bitbucket web hooking

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I'm trying to configure webhook between Jenkins and Bit bucket for a particular branch.

After this, Jenkins job should start if any changes happen in that specific branch, but the first job is triggering when changes happen for any branch.

After that, webhook is working as expected. It will create a problem to copy the existing job as new and forget to check the job trigger.

Is there anyone who faced any issues like this or am I doing any wrong configuration to setup webhook?

Answer (score 0):

By using this [Bitbucket Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket) you can specify the branch name as an option in your job configuration.